# Getting full action name by URL in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

Hi I am new to magento2 and currently I am developing a feature to track when user landed on the product detail page, whether they are from product listing page or other. for this feature I will think of using the HTTP REFERER to construct a request, but I got difficulty due to url got rewrite, I cannot identify by the url pattern, Is there anyway to achieve the full action name to identify where the user come from programmatically? e.g. category_product_view from request getFullActionName.

Comment: Can you show the code you have and where in the code you would like to get the action name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below class in your class dependency & then you will be able to find every information like module name, action name etc.

```
public function __construct(
    RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then you can call below functions to get the action or module name :

```
$moduleName = $this->_request->getModuleName();
$actionName = $this->_request->getActionName();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the tricky point is that this method only can get the current request information, and I can think of every time I may need to trigger a CURL request or file_get_content to the referer url to gather those information and this may cause loading problem. And I am currently still getting stuck on this question and I found that there is a table called url_rewrite in magento which contain the routing information. I am currently trying on querying whether the referer uri is mapped with the request_path field in this table, and use the entity_type field to identify.